# Aws data pipeline trigger aws glue crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-data-pipeline

I have an Aws Data Pipeline with an EMR Activity, which writes data on S3. At the end of this process, it also writes some metadata to a specific S3 folder in that location.

Is there a way to trigger an Aws Glue crawler from within a Data Pipelines definition - which scans this last S3 location, so that it creates an Aws Athena table?

I haven't found a way to do this looking in the Aws Data Pipelines documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`ShellCommandActivity`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html) and call [`aws glue start-crawler`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/start-crawler.html).

Comment: That's the route I got to in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can trigger an AWS Glue crawler from within an AWS Data Pipeline to scan the S3 location containing the metadata and create an AWS Athena table. To achieve this, you can utilize the "ShellCommandActivity" in AWS Data Pipeline to execute AWS CLI commands.